# Wave Analytics shows wrong number of records in Dataset

Tags: data, einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein, data-set

Why is there such a big difference in numbers between the dataset and the number of records in Salesforce.

E.g. I have over 1000+ contracts in Salesforce but it only shows me 400 in the dataset.

Is there anything I need to check? I have refreshed it many times already...enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In data Manager go to 4th Tab setup, there you will see the list of Source Data Replications. Go to your object ie. Contract, click on down arrow & select run replication. So the old copy will get replace with new data.

If that doesn't work, delete that Source Data Replications and dataset and create the new dataset.